# jquery is not reaching css class

Tags: jquery, css

with this jquery, I am trying to delete the css class but it is not doing that one.

```
   $(".validate_txt_sContactPhone.error").next().removeClass("atleastTwoChars");

  <nobr><input name="ctl00$objContentPageTag$spzContactInformation$txt_sContactPhone$txt" type="text" size="25" id="ctl00_objContentPageTag_spzContactInformation_txt_sContactPhone_txt" class="xqh_TextBox_Edit validate_txt_sContactPhone error">
  <div class="atleastTwoChars"></div>
   <label for="ctl00_objContentPageTag_spzContactInformation_txt_sContactPhone_txt" generated="true" class="error">2*</label></nobr>
```

Comment: I think its because you are not being merry enough

Comment: I tried with chrome inspect but couldn't find anything, mind went blank ;)

Comment: print out the value of `validate_txt_sContactPhone`, does it exist?

Comment: The code you provided works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/mER7y/

Comment: Ugh.. code like that is exactly why dotnetdoesnotrock.

Comment: OK, thanks guys !! merry christmas :) @Petah thanks for your christmas gift ( negative point) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine here:
http://jsfiddle.net/sVESR/

My guess would be that the `$(".validate_txt_sContactPhone.error")` selector is grabbing the wrong element from somewhere else on the page.

Answer (score 2):

i would not use `next()` because a browser might insert some node before the next node so you do not want to count on that.
use `nextUntil('.atleastTwoChars')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the script within the `<head>` tags, it will execute before the DOM (document object model) is loaded, so your script won't have any effect. In order to prevent that you must use the `ready` method.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".validate_txt_sContactPhone.error").next().removeClass("atleastTwoChars");
                });
            </script>
</head>
```

But If your script is within the `body`, the `ready` method is not required but you must not forget to set it before the closing `</body>` tag and after your HTML tags.

```
<body>
<input class="validate_txt_sContactPhone error">
<div class="atleastTwoChars"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".validate_txt_sContactPhone.error").next().removeClass("atleastTwoChars");
</script>

</body>
```